# finding existing and non existing rows in a table

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm currently bugged by a simple SQL query and I'm really no SQL expert, so here's my problem.

I have a fairly simple table, with some data :

```
------------------------
| Id | Related | Value |
------------------------
| A  | B       | 1     |
| A  | E       | 2     |
| B  | E       | 3     |
| C  | A       | 2     |
------------------------
```

I would like to query the table on a range of values for the first column. For example, retrieve the values for Id in ('A', 'B', 'E'). So my expected result would be :

```
------------------------
| Id | Related | Value |
------------------------
| A  | B       | 1     |
| A  | E       | 2     |
| B  | E       | 3     |
| E  | null    | null  |
------------------------
```

I know this has to be a simple query, but it eludes me.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried fiddling with some left join on the table itself, but it obviously leads nowhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all your search parameters in a `CTE` or any temp table and do a `LEFT JOIN` with your actual table. Try something like this.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
id CHAR(1),
Related CHAR(1),
Value int
)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('A','B',1),
('A','E',2),
('B','E',3),
('C','A',2)

;WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT 'A' ID UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'E'
)
SELECT CTE.id,t.Related,t.Value
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN @t t  ON CTE.id = t.id
```

Comment: Ok, now I see how I can use this with a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT l.id,d.Related,d.Value
FROM (values ('A'),('B'),('C')) l(id)
LEFT JOIN fairly_simple_table d ON l.id = d.id
```

Comment: This answer is hard coded... I don't see how I could use it.